# Why is vNet Integration breaking the Authentication setup on my Azure Function

Tags: authentication, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function where I have enabled Authentication with the Identity provider being Microsoft.  With Postman, I get my token, call the root page ("Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running"), pass it in the Authorization header and it responds correctly.

Once I enable vNet Integration, the function respond with the error

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

What did I missed?

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if your OpenId configuration is correct? "Unable to download OpenId Connect Configuration"

Comment: I have no idea where the OpenId config is.  Never had to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post is quite old and there is no information on the VNet integration setup, but anyway.

The issue might be because of the VNet Integration setting called `Route All`.
According to [the official Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#application-routing),

> If Route All is disabled, your app only routes private traffic into your virtual network. If you want to route all your outbound app traffic into your virtual network, make sure that Route All is enabled.

So I believe the `Route All` is enabled in your configuration. And you should try to disable it:

1. Go to `Vnet Integration`
2. Disable toggle `Route All` as it is in the screenshot below

[image]